# i am trying to create a windows webviewer in pyhton, i tried python webview but i always get a module error

Tags: python, windows, webview, python-webbrowser, pywebview

why is it that my python webview code does not work

```
import webview
webview.create_window("Ridola Web View", "www.google.com")
webview.start()
```

Giving me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\LiveViewer\webview.py", line 81, in <module>
    import webview
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\LiveViewer\webview.py", line 82, in <module>
    webview.create_window("Ridola Web View", "www.google.com")
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'webview' has no attribute 'create_window' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Rename `webview.py` to something like `my_webview.py`or any other of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

When importing a module or a library, Python looks for it from `sys.path`. If there is a module or a script, which share the same filename as your library, listed before the library in `sys.path`, Python would import the module or the script. In this case, there would be never-ending importing becaue the module or the script is importing itself repeatedly. To avoid such situation, you should avoid naming scripts and modules identical to libraries you wish to import.

If your script or any imported script has the identical filename to `webview`, such as `webview.py`, please rename it to avoid any conflict.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred due to the name of your file.

I guess the name of your Python file is "webview.py" and webview.py is already a dependency when you call,

```
import webview
```

so this led to circular import where the Python file imported itself in an infinite loop.

renaming your file will work well without errors.